# Adding checkbox to a list in grails

Tags: javascript, forms, grails, gsp

The following is the list that i created from the device table in the database. I am printing it using table. For each row i wanted to add checkbox. how exactly can I do that?

```
         <table>
                    <thead>


                    <tr>

                         <g:sortableColumn property="dname" title="${message(code: 'devices.dname.label', default: 'Dname')}" />

                        <g:sortableColumn property="owner" title="${message(code: 'devices.owner.label', default: 'Owner')}" />

                        <g:sortableColumn property="serailNumber" title="${message(code: 'devices.serailNumber.label', default: 'Serail Number')}" />

                        <g:sortableColumn property="supportingAndroidVersion" title="${message(code: 'devices.supportingAndroidVersion.label', default: 'Supporting Android Version')}" />

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <g:each in="${Devices.list()}" status="i" var="devicesInstance">
                    <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">

                        <td>${fieldValue(bean: devicesInstance, field: "dname")}</td>

                        <td>${fieldValue(bean: devicesInstance, field: "owner")}</td>

                        <td>${fieldValue(bean: devicesInstance, field: "serailNumber")}</td>

                        <td>${fieldValue(bean: devicesInstance, field: "supportingAndroidVersion")}</td>

                    </tr>
                </g:each>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table>
                    <thead>


                    <tr>
                         <td></td>
                         <g:sortableColumn property="dname" title="${message(code: 'devices.dname.label', default: 'Dname')}" />

                        <g:sortableColumn property="owner" title="${message(code: 'devices.owner.label', default: 'Owner')}" />

                        <g:sortableColumn property="serailNumber" title="${message(code: 'devices.serailNumber.label', default: 'Serail Number')}" />

                        <g:sortableColumn property="supportingAndroidVersion" title="${message(code: 'devices.supportingAndroidVersion.label', default: 'Supporting Android Version')}" />

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <g:each in="${Devices.list()}" status="i" var="devicesInstance">
                    <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
                        <td><g:checkbox name="myCheckbox${i}" value="${true}"/></td>
                        <td>${fieldValue(bean: devicesInstance, field: "dname")}</td>

                        <td>${fieldValue(bean: devicesInstance, field: "owner")}</td>

                        <td>${fieldValue(bean: devicesInstance, field: "serailNumber")}</td>

                        <td>${fieldValue(bean: devicesInstance, field: "supportingAndroidVersion")}</td>

                    </tr>
                </g:each>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: but you gave the name of the check box as myCheckbox. Then name of checkbox in each row of the table will be mycheckbox . right?

Comment: what I am getting is the following error 'Tag [checkbox] does not exist. No tag library found for namespace: g'

Comment: I don't know why you receive this error, try to clean and run project once again. checkbox is built in tag http://grails.org/doc/2.2.4/ref/Tags/checkBox.html . I answered to your question how to add checkbox for each row....

Comment: got it. its <g:checkBox> not <g:checkbox>